# How Lord venkateshwara and Shiva are different?

Tags: venkateshwara

How lord venkateshwara and parameshwara are different.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE. Are you thinking both are same because they have a common name?

Comment: Shiva is destroyer and one of the trimurti.
Venkateshwara is avatar of Lord Vishnu.

Comment: Venkateshwara is avatar of Bhagwan Vishnu and Shiva is one of the trimurti. for Vaishnavas Venkateshwara or Bhagwan Vishnu is Supreme, for Advaitins they are similar(because they think both are incarnations of bramhan) but not the same, for Shaivites Shiva is Supreme.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE. Try to include some details/explanation about what you're asking the question. Visit [ask]

Answer (score 3):

According to Hindu Mythology
it so simple that

parameshwara is other name of Lord shiva

venkateshwara is Avatar of Lord Vishnu

Comment: Cite some sources to improve your answer.